# Mapping JSON string in parquet file as struct or map in AWS Athena

Tags: json, struct, web-crawler, parquet, amazon-athena

I am trying to map a parquet file which have a few columns in it. One of the column contains JSON object. Other columns are either string or number or date. When I use Athena Crawler to detect the schema of the table to be created it maps all other columns correctly except column with JSON data. It maps this column as string. I was expecting it to be either map or struct.
So alternatively I created a table schema manually and mapped that column as struct. When I query this column from Athena query editor, it shows me below error which probably says that I mapped string as struct. But I know I have valid JSON object in that column. When I created another table with that column mapped as map<string,string>, it still gives me the same error.

> HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://blah/blah/mydata/xyz=1686767400000/part-00001-d624c074-cc8a-4696-a566-b8650581d66c.c000.snappy.parquet (offset=0, length=28353): class org.apache.parquet.io.PrimitiveColumnIO cannot be cast to class org.apache.parquet.io.GroupColumnIO (org.apache.parquet.io.PrimitiveColumnIO and org.apache.parquet.io.GroupColumnIO are in unnamed module of loader io.trino.server.PluginClassLoader @7f2a5d5f)

Is there any way to map JSON data in parquet file as struct? Any pointer would be appreciated.

If I map that column as string then to query the data I have to use the combination of cast and json_extract function. If I can map it as struct then my query syntax would be much simpler.

Comment: You can use the JSON functions in Athena to parse the string. You can also create a view based on such a query.

Comment: yes...I am able to use json_extract function in combination with cast function to get what I want to do. But that makes my where clause complex. If such JSON can be mapped as struct or map then SQL query becomes simpler.

Comment: I understand the query's complexity, which is why I suggested creating a view that will hide this complexity. The users will be able to query the view instead of the original table.